# Change value of input placeholder via model?

Tags: angularjs, pug

I'm trying to change the value of the input placeholder from a controller but cant quite figure out how.

```
input(type='text', ng-model='inputText', side='30', placeholder='enter username')
```

Is there a way to modify a model's element attributes?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You can bind with a variable in the controller:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="inputText" placeholder="{{somePlaceholder}}" />
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.somePlaceholder = 'abc';
```

Comment: it works, however, the whole expression is visible to end users for a brief delay. That's why there are ng-binding.
See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind

Comment: Also, will not work in IE, throwing an error. Presumably same reason why syle="{{}}" is discouraged: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Comment: @BùiThanhHải exactly how would you use ng-bind in this situation?  Got a code sample?

Comment: You example is not working on devices. Keyboard shows but not write

Comment: to accomplish the functionality of ng-bind for attribute use `ng-attr-*attributeName*` as mentioned by [ysub](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37708786/4068027)

Answer (score 21):

The accepted answer still threw a Javascript error in IE for me (for Angular 1.2 at least). It is a bug but the workaround is to use ngAttr detailed on https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation

```
<input type="text" ng-model="inputText" ng-attr-placeholder="{{somePlaceholder}}" />
```

Issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5025

Answer (score 7):

Since AngularJS does not have directive DOM manipulations as jQuery does, a proper way to modify attributes of one element will be using directive.
Through link function of a directive, you have access to both element and its attributes.

Wrapping you whole input inside one directive, you can still introduce ng-model's methods through controller property.

This method will help to decouple the logic of ngmodel with placeholder from controller.
If there is no logic between them, you can definitely go as Wagner Francisco said.

Answer (score 5):

As Wagner Francisco said, (in JADE)

```
input(type="text", ng-model="someModel", placeholder="{{someScopeVariable}}")`
```

And in your controller :

```
$scope.someScopeVariable = 'somevalue'
```

Comment: @cpburnz - This looks like a valid attempt at answering the question to me. If you don't like it, you should downvote it, not flag it for deletion.

Comment: Thats exactly the same answer as @Wagner Francisco